# Configuring Node Reference URL to auto populate with outbound (internal) link (node title)

Tags: nodes, uri, navigation

I have this Node Type called "Services", and I have a Node Type called "Booking". The latter is a form to request a booking of one of the Services. So by default, every "Services" node has a link to this form. I have Installed Node Reference and Node Reference URL and in the form (because of the configuration of  the mentioned modules) I have a Select List where the client can choose all "Services" available (It's the titles of the nodes of the Type "Services")

How could I achieve that, instead of the client having to manually select the Service from the list, it is already marked the title of the node corresponding to the URL the user is accessing the form, from. (meaning where they were at when they clicked the link to the form)

THANK YOU in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the node reference field step 1:
[image: Adding the node reference field]

Adding the node reference field step 2:

a) Choose your Content type from 'Content types that can be referenced ' select list 
b) Fallback behavior *-> choose Use select list widget , leave all other options if you not need

All the settings are over.

Now access your create content type with the node_id, in url

sitename.com/node/add/{the content type}/23, where 23 is the node id passed from the link

You can find that the options with particular node is is selected in the list box

**Creating links - it is well explained in modules readme.txt please go through well**

Comment: Hi Anoop! Thanks for your response and excuse my ignorance, but this snippet should work with Node Reference and Node Reference URL installed, right? And this function I should add to exactly which module? CCK? Or this will work regardless of Node Reference/URL and I could uninstall the module?

Comment: Oh sorry, No need of above snippet. The module installed by you nodereference_url is enough to solve your problem. Are you not getting desired output still using this module.

Comment: Hi again! I do not understand how I should configure it to achieve this. In " Content types that can be references" I have set "Services" which is right, but then in fallback behaviour I have only the following options: "Use autocomplete", "Use Select list" (What Im using), "Display page not found", "LEave this field blank". I do not have an option like "Title of the node you're accessing this form from" (wow, that would be awesome!). Do I require some extra widgets installs or something? I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: I tried these modules and i found it working good, i will post the steps as edit my answer

Comment: i edited my answer, well your configuration was right. all you need is, while  creating your content type pass nid also.